# Populating a SQL table - SQL Server Profiler doesn't pick it up

Tags: sql-server, trace, sql-server-profiler

I am trying to use SQL server profiler to run a trace, to track some 'behind-the-scenes' actions carried out by a piece of software we use that is no longer working or supported but we require for our work. Part of the software uses SQLExpress, so our theory is that if we can alter the SQL tables, SPs etc., we may be able to fix the program. We don't have access to the source code.

I am trying to track a particular table, say dbo.VAL, to work out where its data comes from. I can see the final table in SQL after the program runs, and there are a number of statements in the trace I'm running that relate to the table, but none of them appear to populate it (the first statement creates it as an empty table). However, the final table clearly contains data.

My question is, is there any way this software might have inserted data into the table while the trace was running, that wouldn't show up on the trace? I used default options for my first trace and have tried with some additional options, but the software crawls to a halt when I turn on too many options for the trace, and I don't know which ones are useful for me to try out. (Each run takes 30 mins so 'trying all the combinations' isn't viable...)

---

FURTHER INFO:

These are the statements that show up in the trace related to this particular table, numbered for convenience:

```
1.

if object_id('[dbo].[VAL]','u') is not null

drop table [dbo].[VAL]
create table [dbo].[VAL] (

[field1] bigint, 
[field2] varchar(2000),
 [field3] varchar(2000),
 [field4] varchar(100),
 [field4] varchar(50)

)

2.

CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Table1]
AS

WITH CTE_ErrorOutput AS ( 
SELECT 'Data1' AS  [Fielda1],[Fielda2],[Fielda3],[Fielda4],[Fielda4],[Fielda4] FROM [dbo].[Table2]

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Data2' AS  [field1],[field2],[field3],[field4],[field5],[field6] FROM [dbo].[VAL]

UNION ALL

[[etc.]]

),
CTE_2 AS (
[[etc.]]
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_ErrorOutput
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM CTE_2

3.

create view [dbo].[Table3] as
 select
 Fieldb1,Fieldb2 from
 [dbo].[VAL]

4.

SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE ON; SET FMTONLY ON;Select top 0 * from dbo.VAL SET FMTONLY OFF; SET NO_BROWSETABLE OFF;

5.

select @@trancount; SET FMTONLY ON select * from dbo.VAL SET FMTONLY OFF exec ..sp_tablecollations_100 N'[dbo].[VAL]'

6.

insert bulk dbo.VAL ([field1] BigInt, [field2] VarChar(2000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [field3] VarChar(2000) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [field4] VarChar(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, [field5] VarChar(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)
```

As you can see, 1. drops the table and creates it empty, and 2-3 just *use* the data. 4-6, I am less certain what they do, but again they don't seem to add to the data. sp_tablecollations_100 appears to be a system stored procedure which is related to 'insert bulk'. I suspect 'insert bulk' is what loads the data back out to the software or potentially into a CSV which is what the software outputs.

My goal is just to ascertain what possibilities there are for how the table can have been populated without seeing it in Profiler. I don't necessarily need a fix for it, but in that case I need a way to confirm that there is no possible way to see the population event with the tools I have available.

Comment: `INSERT BULK` is your guy, but if I remember correctly you don't get to see the data in profiler. When you use the bulk interfaces the server starts to execute the request before receiving the whole request. The data is kinda streaming into the table.

Comment: First, the profiler is deprecated since 2012, replaced by extended events. XEs provide a *lot* more events than the old SQL Server Profiler did. Second, you *really* don't want to capture BULK INSERT data - not only would that be a huge amount of data, it would eradicate any benefit you'd get by a bulk operation. Are you looking for *auditing* perhaps?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to find where the data comes from? You can capture the client's IP and application name already. You can capture the bulk operation anyway.

Comment: Here is a related link that might help on DBA: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36604/insert-bulk-in-sql-profiler-without-values

Comment: SMM - that question seems to provide confirmation that Profiler won't pick up the info, but I suppose I also need to know whether there are any other ways of picking it up. Does anyone know if Extended Events would help me in this situation?

Comment: You can profile the (undocumented) `INSERT BULK` command, but you can't see the data. Extended events will not allow you to see the data either. Just about the only thing that can is a trace on the TCP/IP level from something that understands TDS (like Wireshark, though its actual TDS support is a bit spotty). However, it's unclear that you actually need this -- a bulk copy is always a straight insert, so you can be sure that any new records in the table are the actual data that got bulk copied. Any `UPDATE`/`DELETE` that happened afterwards would show up in the profiler trace.